# Secured SSL connection with Mosquitto Broker

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to make a SSL connection with Mosquitto MQTT Broker on Windows.
http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html is the url I used to create certificates and keys:

> CA: ca.key ca.crt
>
> Server: server.key server.crt
>
> Client: client.key client .crt

Then I edited `mosquitto.conf`

```
cafile TestSSL/ca.crt
certfile TestSSL/server.crt
keyfile TestSSL/server.key
require_certificate true
use_identity_as_username true
```

After this Started MQTT Mosquitto Broker:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto>mosquitto.exe -c mosquitto.conf -p 8883 -v
1451296913: mosquitto version 1.4.5 (build date 09/11/2015 14:34:52.97) starting

1451296913: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1451296913: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1451296913: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
```

Tried to subscribe with Broker:

> mosquitto_sub.exe --cafile TestSSL/ca.crt --cert TestSSL/server.crt --key TestSSL/client.key -h 192.168.0.6 -p 8883  -t "TestSSL" -i "TestSSL_1234567890" -d -v

**I see below error at Broker**

```
1451297037: OpenSSL Error: error:140780E5:SSL routines:ssl23_read:ssl
handshake failure 1451297037: Socket error on client <unknown>,
disconnecting.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the client.crt with mosquitto_pub not the server.crt

```
mosquitto_sub.exe --cafile TestSSL/ca.crt --cert TestSSL/client.crt
--key TestSSL/client.key -h 192.168.0.6 -p 8883 -t "TestSSL" -i "TestSSL_1234567890" -d -v
```

Comment: Tried with that but Getting error: OpenSSL Error: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 ale
rt certificate unknown
OpenSSL Error: error:140940E5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl hands
hake failure
1451319223: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 way ssl, you should pack client certificate and client key into a keystore. for instance pack into a p12 file using openssl.